# Deleting database from phpmyadmin. Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, mysqlupgrade

I am using XAAMP 7.4.3-0, and when trying to delete a database from phpmyadmin I get this error. mysql_upgrade has now deprecated so not quite sure how to go about deleting the database. I did update MySQL on my laptop (Mac) but didn't seem to help either.

```
 #1558 - Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20.
 Created with MariaDB 100108, now running 100411.
 Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_upgrade/

Comment: mysql_upgrade is going away for *mysql*, but according to your error message, you're using MariaDB. So as spencer has linked, and as the error message states, you should run `mysql_upgrade` to fix the problem.